# Using Variables in my .env File

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

please any idea on how to set variable in my env files ?

```
Website_Base_URL=https://${websiteId}.dev.net/api
```

in my code I have:

```
websiteId = 55;
```

and I want to call `config.get('Website_Base_URL');` so it returns the full url:

```
https://55.dev.net/api
```

in my default.js I have

```
Website_Base_URL: process.env.Website_Base_URL,
```

Comment: Which part of this is trying to set an env variable?

Comment: meet [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Comment: I want to call config.get('Website_Base_URL'); and passing websiteId as Parameter so it return the parameter + the baseUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @guijob said `dotenv` can be used. You can get process.env from buffer also.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const websiteId = 55;
const buf = Buffer.from(`Website_Base_URL=https://${websiteId}.dev.net/api`);
const config = dotenv.parse(buf) // will return an object

/// this below is from dotenv `config()` function

Object.keys(config).forEach(function (key) {
  if (!process.env.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    process.env[key] = parsed[key]
  }
})
```